# If ten points are on a unit square, one pair is at most $\sqrt2/3$ apart

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

Ten points are placed in a unit square. Show that there is a pair of points at most $\sqrt2/3$ apart. 
I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem, and have not had any luck so far.

Comment: Closely related: circle packing

Comment: Try an incremental approach: 2 points can be at most $\sqrt{2}$ apart. How about adding a 3rd point? Where do we place it to maximize the minimum distance between any 2 points?

Comment: Would that be $\frac {\sqrt 2}{3}$? Packing problems like this sometimes yield to pigeonhole arguments.

Comment: Can you please outline the arguments used to get to the answer? I understand that this lends itself quite nicely to the pigeonhole principle, but need to solve this quickly atm.

Comment: Hint: Divide the square into $9$ identical squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: How would you go about dividing a square into nine pigeonholes so that two of the points would be in the same one?

If this really is Olympiad Training much better to take some time and solve it for yourself.

Comment: @Kinhu I was on an Olympiad Team quite a long time ago - I wish you well with your training. You will get some problems along the way which you have a good idea how to solve. And you will find others which look like nothing you have seen before, or where the idea isn't obvious. When someone tells you the idea the thing becomes rather easier - you will get a lot out of working things out for yourself - that was how I learned to deal with hard problems.

Answer (score 2):

After receiving some tips, I now know how to proceed.The diagonals of the square are √2 long, so after dividing the initial square into 9 smaller squares, the diagonals are √2/3 long, and by the pigeon hole principle, the required results falls through